# Mayflash GC controller adapter lag using 1 of 2 USBs

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I recently bought two of the new [Mayflash controller adapter](http://www.play-asia.com/gamecube-controller-adapter-for-wii-u-pc-usb-paOS-13-49-en-70-8h2n.html) and am surprised by the fact that it has two USB connectors. The Wii U only has 2 USB ports, so if I use both connectors I can't connect two adapters at the same time. However, it also works if you use only one of the two USB ports.

The back of the box says that it "supports the built-in Vibration Feedback with no delays by plugging the two USB ports of the adapter into your Wii U system or PC USB connector ports." I've never been good at sensing input lag (I subliminally compensate for it) but other players seem to mind.

What I want to know is, how much lag will I have using only one USB connector with vibration feedback enabled, and how much with vibration feedback disabled?

Comment: It likely needs 2 USB ports due to the power output of the WiiU's USB ports and the power requirements of the adapter.

Comment: For reference, the Nintendo branded Gamecube adapter *also* uses 2 USB ports.

Comment: Ah, that's good info. I couldn't find that either. Thanks!

Comment: I havent noticed lag of any significance with my adapter - Nor have my roommates

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I don't own a WiiU.

From everything I could find out, the WiiU has 4 USB ports.

- 2 under the front flap (USB ports on the right)

[image: WiiU with open front flap]

- 2 on the back

[image: WiiU rear]

I can't be exactly sure why the WiiU GameCube adapters requires two USB ports, although at a guess it has to do with power consumption.

However, since the system was hiding two USB ports on you, as long as you don't need any other USB devices connected while playing Smash, you should be able to connect two of these at once for an 8-player game.

Comment: I am absolutely stupid, thank you for clarifying. This solves my issue, but I'd still like to know the answer to the lag question.